# Install apps to sd card by default

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

How can I do this? I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Ace

I've tried this method http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1278349
I confirmed that it was indeed set to 2. But it wouldnt work.

Then I rooted my phone, installed an app with which I could modify the default installation path, but it also wouldnt work.

What can I do?

Comment: @Izzy I don't think this is a duplicate. The questioner has tried the method proposed to answer the other question, and it hasn't worked.

Comment: @DanHulme Has he? I see nothing of this mentioned here. Sorry if I missed it. Hidden behind some "external link without excerpt"? I cannot even find the word "adb" here. And the only answer I can see at least *pointing* to that has no comments.

Answer (score 4):

With 2.3, it will install apps by default to the external SD card.  However, this will *only* happen if the app can *run* from the SD card.  Many apps **must** be installed onto the internal storage in order to work properly.

Comment: Note to Matthew Read: the *phone* SD card and internal storage are the same thing, as opposed to the *external* SD card.  However, I agree someone could take the wording as ambiguous if they weren't reading closely.

Answer (score 2):

From Google:

> App installation on external storage media
>   The Android platform now allows applications to request installation onto the device's external storage media (such as the SD card), as an alternative to installation onto the device's internal memory.
>
> Application developers can express the preferred installation location for their applications by means of a new attribute of  in the manifest file, android:installLocation. The attribute supports three values: "internalOnly", "preferExternal", and "auto". At install time, the system checks the value of android:installLocation and installs the application .apk according to the preferred location, if possible. If the application has requested external installation, the system installs it into a private, encrypted partition in the external media. Once an application .apk is installed externally, the system lets the user change the storage location of the .apk and move it onto the device's internal memory if needed (and vice versa), through Manage Applications in the user settings.
>
> By default, the system installs all applications onto the device's internal memory, except for those that explicitly request external installation. This means that the system will always install legacy applications onto internal memory, since they do not have access to the android:installLocation attribute. However, it is possible to configure and compile a legacy application such that it is installed internally on older versions of the platform and externally on Android 2.2 and later platforms, if necessary.
>
> Note that requesting installation onto the device's external media is not suitable for all applications, particularly because the external media may be removable and unmounting/remounting may disrupt the user experience and system settings.
>
> For more information about setting a preferred install location for your application, including a discussion of what types of applications should and should not request external installation, please read the [App Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html) document.

Answer (score 1):

Use [link2sd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en). It's a very nice app. You can even set it to automatically move applications to the sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps in the provided [link](http://androinica.com/2010/08/how-to-install-apps-to-the-sd-card-by-default-on-android-2-2-froyo/) and it will work like a charm, works for me :)

and if your a developer and want to add your application directly into sd card then add below line in manifest tag

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```