# Storing Apps on internal storage

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, applications, internal-storage, karbonn-a15

I have recently bought Karbonn A15, i am facing 2 problems in it.

1. How to Store images taken from the camera to SD Card, currently its storing in Internal Storage, i have 8GB of External Storage, but just have 2.5GB of internal
2. How to store apps in internal storage, currently it by default stores on system space, i have 2.5GB of internal storage but just have 581MB of system space.

Can anyone tell me how can i do the settings for the above things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer to your questions:

1. In many cases, the camera app itself offers to chose the storage for images/videos. Check its settings for an item called "storage". If it's not there, you could try to use a symlink of the `DCIM` folder to the sdcard.
2. That's a case for App2SD -- but depends on whether the apps support it or not. You can check this e.g. in *Settings→Apps→Manage Apps*. If supported by the app, you should be able to move it out of the "system space" from here.

### As for where an app is installed by default, mostly depends on two things:

1. what the developer specified in his apps `Manifest` for the install location (see [App Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) in the developer's documentation)
2. what the user defined in the Android settings as default install location (see e.g. [How to Install Android Apps to the SD Card by Default & Move Almost Any App to the SD Card](http://www.howtogeek.com/114667/))

### Related information:

- [Install apps to sd card by default](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22452/16575)
- [Setting default install path in android](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1278349) (xda-developers)
- [Set The Storage Card As The Default Install Location In Android](http://socialtimes.com/set-the-storage-card-as-the-default-install-location-in-android_b47794) (socialtimes.com)

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, just wanted to know that if there is internal storage available, why its storing apps in system space... i am not asking on SD card but atleast it should store on internal storage by default. because even if i move the app it does not totally move to internal storage, it still have some portion in system space.

Comment: That has to do with two things: a) default settings on your device, and b) default definitions in the Manifest of the app. I will add some details to my answer.