# why can't i move certain apps from sd card to internal memory on android LG-L38c touchscreen phone?

Tags: storage

Why are some apps i download and install saving to sd card instead of internal memory? I have more space on internal than sd card and it won't let me move some apps to internal memory.

Answer (score 2):

In the `Manifest` of the `.apk` file, developers can specify where they prefer there app to go. When that request can be met (technically), it will. The different possibilities include e.g.

- no preference set: Goes to "internal storage"
- `preferExternal`: Goes to SDCard (if available), else internal storage
- set to "auto": if the app has widgets or declares services, it goes to internal storage. Otherwise it depends on device settings.

See also my answers [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/40499/16575) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/43522/16575) – the latter answer also details how you can (partially) override this.